# Análise de Propensao de Cliente - Servico de agendamento - Variavel_Target

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estou começando dar os primeiros passos em `machine-learning` e gostaria de aplicar uma análise de prospecção à cada cliente, de acordo com o respectivo serviço de agendamento.

Tenho uma carteira de clientes que tem um ou mais produtos ativos. A cada um período - aproximadamente 6 meses - a referida carteira precisa ser submetida à manutenção.

A empresa tem um serviço proativo para agendamento do serviço. O cliente pode optar em agendar o serviço ou ir diretamente à assistência técnica.

O objetivo do estudo é `identificar` quais clientes tem maior prospecção para tal agendamento.

Exemplo:

Considere um cliente `X` com 2 produtos - Prod_A e Prod_B - e que precisou de 4 manutenções no ano - Prod_A-Man_01, Prod_A-Man_02, Prod_B-Man_01 e Prod_B-Man_02.
Porém, tenho dúvidas na preparação dos dados. As dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. Qual deve ser a minha variável `target`?

A variável target "Agendou: Sim/Não" para cada uma das manutenções do cliente ou
devo considerar o cliente apenas 1 vez e trabalhar com a variável target "% de Agendamento"  contabilizando quantas vezes o cliente agendou do total de 4 manutenções que ele tinha para realizar.

2. Quais os modelos indicados para esse tipo de análise?

Comment: É sempre importante ter o problema de negocio bem definido antes de começar. Não existe 'certo e errado', existe o que você quer como resultado final. Sem conhecer os seus dados é difícil te propor algo pois eu não conheço as outras variáveis e não sei quais delas são importantes, sem seu conjunto de dados também é difícil falar qual modelo de machine learning vai se adaptar melhor ao problema proposto. Caso sua regra de negocio seja X você pode agrupar, caso seja Y você pode considerar o cliente apenas uma vez. Tudo depende do seu problema de negocio e da regra de negocio. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Para ter uma melhor ideia, só realizando uma análise exploratória. Me vem em mente algumas questões, tais como:

- O perfil do cliente que fez agendamento está relacionado com produtos de forma individual ou geral?
- Qual (ou quais) item tem maior relevância com agendamentos por parte do cliente?
- Qual (ou quais) item gera menor engajamento?
- Sexo, idade, etc, influenciam no engajamento?

A partir desse estudo exploratório e plotagens, você poderia entender qual comportamento de cada cliente para cada produto e, só a partir daí, achar um modelo adequado. O mais básico seria uma [regressão logística](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_log%C3%ADstica) ou ainda uma [árvore de decisão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_de_decis%C3%A3o), aplicando algum tratamento sob as variáveis.

Especialmente na árvore de decisão, talvez você consiga simplificar fazendo transformação para variáveis qualitativas. Se ajudar, dá uma olhada num exemplo básico no meu [github](https://github.com/msbruno/python-data-science/blob/master/BreastCancerData.ipynb)

Comment: Muito obrigada Bruno.